# pagenote{} in section{} gives correct output in pdflatex, but not in tex4ebook output in epub

Tags: sectioning, tex4ebook, pagenote

This MWE shows the problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote

\begin{document}

\section[Some section title]{Some section title\protect\pagenote{Some pagenote, see \fullcite{sigfridsson}} \\in two lines}

This pagenote is shown correctly in pdflatex.

But with tex4ebook it is shown twice in the printnotes
and gives an error with epubcheck.

\printnotes

\end{document}
```

How to fix this situation?

**Update 1 -- The myconfig.cfg file --**
Wenn I do `not` use the `-e build.lua` the error remains.
Wenn I do `not` use the `myconfig.cfg` the error disappears.
`myconfig.cfg:`

```
\let\oldclrearpage\clearpage
% define macro for newpage insertion
\def\mypagebreak{\Configure{newpage}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<div class="newpage"></div>}}}

\Preamble{xhtml,no-cut,3,info}

\Configure{CoverMimeType}{image/jpeg}
\Configure{CoverImage}{}{}
%
% enforce newpage
%
% define it for \newpage
%
\mypagebreak
\Css{.newpage{page-break-before:always;}}
% modify \Configure{BODY} so our confiurations work on all extracted pages
\Configure{@BODY}{\def\clearpage{\bgroup\mypagebreak\oldclrearpage\egroup}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\global\let\clearpage\oldclrearpage\Configure{newpage}{}}

\begin{document}
\Configure{DocumentLanguage}{de}
\Configure{OpfScheme}{ISBN}
\Configure{UniqueIdentifier}{3-0000-1111-X}
\EndPreamble
```

Does it reproduce the error in epubcheck? And the doubling within the notes?

Comment: Do  you use custom configuration files for Pagenotes, or the one contained in TeX Live? I don't get any errors with vanilla TeX Live 2023.

Comment: Within the last 4 weeks we had some configurations, also about pagenotes, all that you had suggested for solution of some problems with tex4ebook. I will look in details this evening and add some Update to the question to tell about the configurations used in this MWE. Thank you.

Comment: I added Update 1 with myconfig.cfg. Does it reproduce the error also in your system?

Comment: I can see it now. It seems that it is caused by the `no-cut,3` options in the `\Preamble` command. Do you really need these options?

Comment: Oh, these two options seem to stay there for a starting understanding reason. When omitting, as far as I can see, I get an adequate epub which satisfies my needs. And also: a 0 0 0 0 error epubcheck. So obviously I do not need these two options. Thank you for caring, Michal!

Comment: Ah, good to know. These options can be useful if you want to break sections to separate files yourself. I don't fully understand why  it doesn't work well in this case, so I am glad that you don't need them.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this info; I think that in all my current projects I do not need these two options at all, since I can not see that separate files for the separate sections would be of any benefit for the epub output. So I will change this in the preamble of all the myconfigX.cfg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

michal.h21 gave the decisive hint for the solution of this question:

I `do not need` the two options `no-cut` and `3` in the
`\Preamble{xhtml,no-cut,3,info}` of `myconfig.cfg` when using `tex4ebook`.

So I deleted it and got adequate results and no error with `epubcheck`, so that this solved the case.